# Bazel - how to determine targets that need rebuilding?

Tags: bazel, monorepo

If I have a monorepo using bazel, how can I get a list of targets that need to be rebuilt for the current commit, compared to the previous commit?

Ideally, there would be a way to work back from the changed sources file to the immediate and transitive targets that require them.

If I know which targets needed a rebuild, I will know which components I'll need to redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there aren't any out-of-the-box solutions to this right now. See this discussion of a similar question:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/bazel-discuss/I9udqWIcEdI/discussion